# Setup Travis-CI with Laravel 5 and PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, travis-ci

After migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL, I've been having problems integrating Laravel 5.1 with Travis-CI. I've tried the following configuration:

**.env.travis**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString

DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=CDJ_BD
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

**.travis.yml**

```
language: php

php:
  - 7.0

addons:
  postgresql: "9.4"

before_install:
  - composer self-update
  - cp .env.travis .env
  - psql -c 'create database CDJ_BD;' -U postgres

install:
  - composer require phpunit/phpunit:4.8.* satooshi/php-coveralls:dev-master
  - composer install --dev

script:
  - php artisan migrate --seed
  - ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-clover ./tests/logs/clover.xml

after_script:
- php vendor/bin/coveralls -v
```

**database.php**

```
...
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
'connections' => [
        'testing' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'CDJ_BD'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'CDJ_BD'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],
    ],
    ...
```

After running `php artisan migrate --seed`, the following exception is thrown:

```
[PDOException]                                                
  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  database "CDJ_BD" does not exist
```

My MySQL configuration was pretty similar and ran without any problems. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: `env('DB_DATABASE', 'CDJ_BD'),` The CAPS databasename looks suspect. In any case, you could check the Postgres logfile.

Comment: Wow, that was the problem, in fact. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by wildplasser, the problem was the CAPS database name in `env('DB_DATABASE', 'CDJ_BD'),` in database.php and in the .travis files. Switching them all to lowercase `'cdj_bd'` solved the problem.